# Downloading Data from Access using a Month-End Date and a Function

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm new to VBA and am writing a macro that downloads data from Access based on a month-end date entered by the user.

Currently, I am having issues getting information to download from Access.

To be more specific: when I run the macro and enter in the month-end date, no data is downloaded but I also receive no error messages.

I have been trying different code iterations to try to get it to work. Before I was getting various error messages; now I get no error messages but no data downloads.

I was reading online that I need to use a function to get my variable from the input box (`box`) to work in the Access query. I am wondering if it has to do with how I have my function set up. Or is there an issue with my Access query.

```
Sub Expense_Download()
    '
    ' Expense_Download Macro
    '
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, sQRY As String, strFilePath As String, box As Variant, myvar As Variant
    strFilePath = "C:\Users\NVanWyk\Documents\Fidato\Lunch And Learn\Lunch and Learn Access DB\Nate's Expenses DB.accdb"   'Replace the ‘DatabaseFolder’ and ‘myDB.accdb’ with your DB path and DB name

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    box = InputBox("What month do you want expense data for? Please use the MM/DD/YYYY format.", "Expense Month?")

    If Not IsDate(box) Then MsgBox "Value entered is not a valid date, please try again.", , "Input Value is Not Correct"
    End

    myvar = box

    cnn.Open "provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";"
    'have to indent the data source or the code does not run

    sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Expenses Where Expenses.Expense_Month=myvar()" 'Replace ‘tblData’ with your Access DB Table name or Query name from which you want to download the data"

    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open myvar(), sQRY, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    'sheet 1 for whatever reason still pastes to the "expense" sheet

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: In your query string, replace `myvar()` with a formatted string like #06/17/2019#

Comment: @KenWhite I apologize for not being specific enough. When I run the macro and enter in the month end date, no data is downloaded but I also receive no error messages. I have been trying different code iterations to try to get it to work. Before I was getting various error codes, now I get none but no data downloads. I was reading online that I need to use a function to get my variable from the input box to work in the access query.

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question, so it can be readily seen, rather than burying it in a comment.

Comment: @KenWhite done, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the line that contains the word 'End' only, will stop execution.

If you want to stop execution in case of wrong user input, do this:

```
If Not IsDate(box) Then
    MsgBox "Value entered is not a valid date, please try again.", , "Input Value is Not Correct"
    End 'or Exit Sub
End If
```

You store the user's month input in myvar variable but then you don't actually put into the select query.

Instead of this:

```
sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Expenses Where Expenses.Expense_Month=myvar()"
```

Try this:

```
sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Expenses Where Expenses.Expense_Month= " & myvar
```

However, the value you are expecting in InputBox is not obvious. I'm assuming that it's a number between 1 and 12 and Expense_Month field is a number too in your database.
In case it contains the year too in YYYY-MM format and is a varchar, you will need to change your code like this:

```
sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Expenses Where Expenses.Expense_Month= '" & myvar & "'"
```

Either of the above is true, IsDate is not the right function to check whether the input is correct. For example if the user types 20 into the box, it will return True as it is a date but January 20 of 1900.

Also, remove the first parameter *myvar()* from this line.

```
rs.Open myvar(), sQRY, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

rs.Open sQRY, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Based on your additional input I recommend using YYYY-MM-DD as user input. So your query would be defined as:

```
sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Expenses Where Expenses.Expense_Month= '" & myvar & "'"
```

To test your query, open Locals windows in VB editor, see what the value of sQRY is once execution reaches this point and run that in Access's SQL editor to see if it is going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The variable I am asking for in the query is meant to be in the MM/DD/YYYY format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone!

I made the edits above and did some other research and was able to get the code to work. I think the snag was because I was using a date (`MM/DD/YYYY`) as the variable, I needed to add the `#` signs in the query so that Access recognized the variable as a date.

```
Sub Expense_Download()
    '
    ' Expense_Download Macro
    '
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, sQRY As String, strFilePath As String, box As Variant, myvar As Variant

    strFilePath = "C:\Users\NVanWyk\Documents\Fidato\Lunch And Learn\Lunch and Learn Access DB\Nate's Expenses DB.accdb"   'Replace the ‘DatabaseFolder’ and ‘myDB.accdb’ with your DB path and DB name

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    box = InputBox("What month do you want expense data for? Please use the MM/DD/YYYY format.", "Expense Month?")
    If Not IsDate(box) Then
        MsgBox "Value entered is not a valid date, please try again.", , "Input Value is Not Correct"
        End
    End If
    myvar = box

    cnn.Open "provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";"
    'have to indent the data source or the code does not run

    sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Expenses Where Expenses.Expense_Month= #" & myvar & "#" 'Replace ‘tblData’ with your Access DB Table name or Query name from which you want to download the data"
    ' access query
    ' # before and after the "myvar" variable are necessary for access to recognize the variable as a date and to run the query successfully.

    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    rs.Open sQRY, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    'sheet 1 for whatever reason still pastes to the "expense" sheet

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-2017), the preferred, programming industry best practice to bind data safely to prepared SQL statements beyond VBA and MS Access. A malicious, clever user can run sql injection from the user input. Maybe not Access but another RDBMS backend.